# Installing Win2D.win81 as NuGet package. Target Framework not compatible

Tags: c#, wpf, win2d

So I am currently trying to install Win2D.win81 as a NuGet package via VS2015s package manager. My goal is to rewrite a simple graphing library I made to now work with a WPF control instead of winforms and benefit from the performance of Win2D vs GDI+.

To do that I made a new ClassLibrary project and added a userControl (WPF). Now I am trying to add Win2D via the package manger to the project but it keeps rejecting telling me the package doesn't target my target framework. Which wasn't that big of a deal if I haven't tried setting my project to target .Net 3.5 to 4.6.2 and any version in between and it always kept rejecting to install.

Excat error from PM:

> Could not install package 'Win2D.win81 1.20.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Win2D.win81` targets Windows 8.1 Store and Windows Phone 8.1 apps, which is a separate .net framework from the full .net 4.6 framework that you are trying to use.